# Check if point is inside a polygon with a buffer

Tags: georuby

I have a geojson and a point (lat,lon). I need to figure out if the point is in the area defined by geojson. But the constraint is relaxed i.e. if the point is inside or within say 0.5 miles from the outer edge of geojson, the point can be considered to be in the area.

Is there a way to do this using georuby?